# Is there a nice MongoDB framework for C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, mongodb

I have been using Mongoid for a Ruby project which makes dealing with MongoDB a piece of cake.

I am now using MongoDB with a .NET (C#) project and am finding the Mongo drivers to be fairly lacking in comparison to Mongoid. Is there something I can use which can at least take care of basic data relationships for me? (like two-way ID references)?

Answer (score 2):

> The best one I could find and I have used in my projects is  the
>   official driver from the MongoDb from 10gen:
>   http://www.10gen.com/
>
> [Example Project](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/10/13/experimenting-with-mongodb-from-c.aspx)
>
> [C# driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/downloads)
>
> [C# driver with Linq tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+LINQ+Tutorial#CSharpDriverLINQTutorial-SupportedLINQqueryoperators)

Comment: The project link does not work you can use google cache.
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:pqeaYq5qP-0J:odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/10/13/experimenting-with-mongodb-from-c.aspx+&cd=1&hl=tr&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Comment: I approve this official driver. It's under rapid development, so if something isn't supported yet, check back in a month or two and it probably is supported. Also, they are responsive to issues logged in their [JIRA issue tracker](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP).